# Use a dope vector to access arbitrary axial slices of a multidimensional array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, slice, matrix-multiplication, transpose

I'm building a suite of functions to work with a [multidimensional-array data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023867/how-can-i-work-with-dynamically-allocated-arbitrary-dimensional-arrays/30023868#30023868) and I want to be able to define arbitrary *slices* of the arrays so I can implement a generalized inner product of two arbitrary matrices (aka *Tensors* or *n-d arrays*).

An APL paper I read (I honestly can't find which -- I've read so many) defines the matrix product on left-matrix `X` with dimensions `A;B;C;D;E;F` and right-matrix `Y` with dimensions `G;H;I;J;K` where `F==G` as

```
Z <- X +.× Y
Z[A;B;C;D;E;H;I;J;K] <- +/ X[A;B;C;D;E;*] × Y[*;H;I;J;K]
```

where `+/` is *sum of*, and × applies element-by-element to two vectors of the same length.

So I need "row" slices of the left and "column" slices of the right. I can of course take a transpose and then a "row" slice to simulate a "column" slice, but I'd rather do it more elegantly.

Wikipedia's article on [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing) leads to a stub about [dope vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dope_vector) which seem to be the miracle cure I'm looking for, but there's not a lot there to go on.

How do I use a dope vector to implement arbitrary slicing?

(Much later I did notice [Stride of an array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array) which has some details.)

Comment: *How do I use a dope vector to implement arbitrary slicing?*  Write in Fortran, or any other language which implements 'real' (as in genuine rather than as in numbers) multi-dimensional arrays.  Even if you don't want to step over to the dark side this -- https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/510871 -- may be informative.

Comment: Similar facility in [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

Comment: What I've here called a *weight vector* is also sometimes called an *extension vector* or *power vector*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Definition

> General array slicing can be implemented (whether or not built into the language) by referencing every array through a dope vector or descriptor — a record that contains the address of the first array element, and then the range of each index and the corresponding coefficient in the indexing formula. This technique also allows immediate array transposition, index reversal, subsampling, etc. For languages like C, where the indices always start at zero, the dope vector of an array with d indices has at least 1 + 2d parameters.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing#Details

That's a dense paragraph, but it's actually all in there. So we need a data structure like this:

```
struct {
    TYPE *data;  //address of first array element
    int rank; //number of dimensions
    int *dims; //size of each dimension
    int *weight; //corresponding coefficient in the indexing formula
};
```

Where `TYPE` is whatever the element type is, the *field* of the matrices. For simplicity and concreteness, we'll just use `int`. For my own purposes, I've devised an encoding of various types into [integer handles](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.apl/KSwo40-eLKI/discussion) so `int` does the job for *me*, YMMV.

```
typedef struct arr { 
    int rank; 
    int *dims; 
    int *weight; 
    int *data; 
} *arr;
```

All of the pointer members can be assigned locations within the 
same allocated block of memory as the struct itself (which we will 
call the header). But by replacing the earlier use of offsets 
and struct-hackery, the implementation of algorithms can be made 
independent of that actual memory layout within (or without) the 
block.

The basic memory layout for a self-contained array object is

```
rank dims weight data 
     dims[0] dims[1] ... dims[rank-1] 
     weight[0] weight[1] ... weight[rank-1] 
     data[0] data[1] ... data[ product(dims)-1 ]
```

An indirect array sharing data (whole array or 1 or more row-slices) 
will have the following memory layout

```
rank dims weight data 
     dims[0] dims[1] ... dims[rank-1] 
     weight[0] weight[1] ... weight[rank-1] 
     //no data! it's somewhere else!
```

And an indirect array containing an orthogonal slice along 
another axis will have the same layout as a basic indirect array, 
but with dims and weight suitably modified.

The access formula for an element with indices (i0 i1 ... iN) 
is

```
a->data[ i0*a->weight[0] + i1*a->weight[1] + ... 
          + iN*a->weight[N] ]
```

, assuming each index i[j] is between [ 0 ... dims[j] ).

In the `weight` vector for a normally laid-out *row-major* array, each element is the product of all lower dimensions.

```
for (int i=0; i<rank; i++)
    weight[i] = product(dims[i+1 .. rank-1]);
```

So for a 3×4×5 array, the metadata would be

```
{ .rank=3, .dims=(int[]){3,4,5}, .weight=(int[]){4*5, 5, 1} }
```

or for a 7×6×5×4×3×2 array, the metadata would be

```
{ .rank=6, .dims={7,6,5,4,3,2}, .weight={720, 120, 24, 6, 2, 1} }
```

### Construction

So, to create one of these, we need the same helper function from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023867/how-can-i-work-with-dynamically-allocated-arbitrary-dimensional-arrays) to compute the size from a list of dimensions.

```
/* multiply together rank integers in dims array */
int productdims(int rank, int *dims){
    int i,z=1;
    for(i=0; i<rank; i++)
        z *= dims[i];
    return z;
}
```

To allocate, simply `malloc` enough memory and set the pointers to the appropriate places.

```
/* create array given rank and int[] dims */
arr arraya(int rank, int dims[]){
    int datasz;
    int i;
    int x;
    arr z;
    datasz=productdims(rank,dims);
    z=malloc(sizeof(struct arr)
            + (rank+rank+datasz)*sizeof(int));

    z->rank = rank;
    z->dims = z + 1;
    z->weight = z->dims + rank;
    z->data = z->weight + rank;
    memmove(z->dims,dims,rank*sizeof(int));
    for(x=1, i=rank-1; i>=0; i--){
        z->weight[i] = x;
        x *= z->dims[i];
    }

    return z;
}
```

And using the same trick from the previous answer, we can make a variable-argument interface to make usage easier.

```
/* load rank integers from va_list into int[] dims */
void loaddimsv(int rank, int dims[], va_list ap){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<rank; i++){
        dims[i]=va_arg(ap,int);
    }
}

/* create a new array with specified rank and dimensions */
arr (array)(int rank, ...){
    va_list ap;
    //int *dims=calloc(rank,sizeof(int));
    int dims[rank];
    int i;
    int x;
    arr z;

    va_start(ap,rank);
    loaddimsv(rank,dims,ap);
    va_end(ap);

    z = arraya(rank,dims);
    //free(dims);
    return z;
}
```

And even automatically produce the *rank* argument by counting the other arguments using the awesome powers of [ppnarg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6722112/733077).

```
#define array(...) (array)(PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__),__VA_ARGS__) /* create a new array with specified dimensions */
```

Now constructing one of these is very easy.

```
arr a = array(2,3,4);  // create a dynamic [2][3][4] array
```

### Accessing elements

An element is retrieved with a function call to `elema` which multiplies each index by the corresponding weight, sums them, and indexes the `data` pointer. We return a pointer to the element so it can be read or modified by the caller.

```
/* access element of a indexed by int[] */
int *elema(arr a, int *ind){
    int idx = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<a->rank; i++){
        idx += ind[i] * a->weight[i];
    }
    return a->data + idx;
}
```

The same varargs trick can make an easier interface `elem(a,i,j,k)`.

### Axial Slices

To take a slice, first we need a way of specifying which dimensions to extract and which to collapse. If we just need to select a single index or all elements from a dimension, then the `slice` function can take *rank* `int`s as arguments and interpret -1 as selecting the whole dimension or 0..*dims<sub>i</sub>*-1 as selecting a single index.

```
/* take a computed slice of a following spec[] instructions
   if spec[i] >= 0 and spec[i] < a->rank, then spec[i] selects
      that index from dimension i.
   if spec[i] == -1, then spec[i] selects the entire dimension i.
 */
arr slicea(arr a, int spec[]){
    int i,j;
    int rank;
    for (i=0,rank=0; i<a->rank; i++)
        rank+=spec[i]==-1;
    int dims[rank];
    int weight[rank];
    for (i=0,j=0; i<rank; i++,j++){
        while (spec[j]!=-1) j++;
        if (j>=a->rank) break;
        dims[i] = a->dims[j];
        weight[i] = a->weight[j];
    }   
    arr z = casta(a->data, rank, dims);
    memcpy(z->weight,weight,rank*sizeof(int));
    for (j=0; j<a->rank; j++){
        if (spec[j]!=-1)
            z->data += spec[j] * a->weight[j];
    }   
    return z;
}
```

All the dimensions and weights corresponding to the -1s in the argument array are collected and used to create a new array header. All arguments >= 0 are multiplied by their associated weight and added to the `data` pointer, *offsetting* the pointer to the correct element.

In terms of the array access formula, we're treating it as a polynomial.

```
offset = constant + sum_i=0,n( weight[i] * index[i] )
```

So for any dimension from which we're selecting a single element (+ all lower dimensions), we factor-out the now-constant index and add it to the constant term in the formula (which in our C representation is the `data` pointer itself).

The helper function `casta` creates the new array header with shared `data`. `slicea` of course changes the weight values, but by calculating weights itself, `casta` becomes a more generally usable function. It can even be used to construct a dynamic array structure that operates directly on a regular C-style multidimensional array, thus *casting*.

```
/* create an array header to access existing data in multidimensional layout */
arr casta(int *data, int rank, int dims[]){
    int i,x;
    arr z=malloc(sizeof(struct arr)
            + (rank+rank)*sizeof(int));

    z->rank = rank;
    z->dims = z + 1;
    z->weight = z->dims + rank;
    z->data = data;
    memmove(z->dims,dims,rank*sizeof(int));
    for(x=1, i=rank-1; i>=0; i--){
        z->weight[i] = x;
        x *= z->dims[i];
    }

    return z;
}
```

### Transposes

The dope vector can also be used to implement transposes. The order of the dimensions (and indices) can be changed.

Remember that this is not a normal 'transpose' like everybody else 
does. We don't rearrange the data at all. This is more 
properly called a 'dope-vector pseudo-transpose'. 
Instead of changing the data, we just change the 
constants in the access formula, rearranging the 
coefficients of the polynomial. In a real sense, this 
is just an application of the commutativity and 
associativity of addition.

So for concreteness, assume the data is arranged 
sequentially starting at hypothetical address 500.

```
500: 0 
501: 1 
502: 2 
503: 3 
504: 4 
505: 5 
506: 6
```

if a is rank 2, dims {1, 7), weight (7, 1), then the 
sum of the indices multiplied by the associated weights 
added to the initial pointer (500) yield the appropriate 
addresses for each element

```
a[0][0] == *(500+0*7+0*1) 
a[0][1] == *(500+0*7+1*1) 
a[0][2] == *(500+0*7+2*1) 
a[0][3] == *(500+0*7+3*1) 
a[0][4] == *(500+0*7+4*1) 
a[0][5] == *(500+0*7+5*1) 
a[0][6] == *(500+0*7+6*1)
```

So the dope-vector pseudo-transpose rearranges the 
weights and dimensions to match the new ordering of 
indices, but the sum remains the same. The initial 
pointer remains the same. The data does not move.

```
b[0][0] == *(500+0*1+0*7) 
b[1][0] == *(500+1*1+0*7) 
b[2][0] == *(500+2*1+0*7) 
b[3][0] == *(500+3*1+0*7) 
b[4][0] == *(500+4*1+0*7) 
b[5][0] == *(500+5*1+0*7) 
b[6][0] == *(500+6*1+0*7)
```

### Inner Product (aka Matrix Multiplication)

So, by using general slices or transpose+"row"-slices (which are easier), generalized inner product can be implemented.

First we need the two helper functions for applying a binary operation to two vectors producing a vector result, and reducing a vector with a binary operation producing a scalar result.

As in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960273/how-to-pass-a-c-math-operator-into-a-function-result-mathfuncx-y) we'll pass in the operator, so the same function can be used with many different operators. For the style here, I'm passing operators as single characters, so there's already an indirect mapping from C operators to *our function's* operators. This is an [x-macro table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635851/real-world-use-of-x-macros/6636596#6636596).

```
#define OPERATORS(_) \
    /* f  F id */ \
    _('+',+,0) \
    _('*',*,1) \
    _('=',==,1) \
    /**/

#define binop(X,F,Y) (binop)(X,*#F,Y)
arr (binop)(arr x, char f, arr y); /* perform binary operation F upon corresponding elements of vectors X and Y */
```

The extra element in the table is for the `reduce` function for the case of a null vector argument. In that case, reduce should return the operator's *identity element*, 0 for `+`, 1 for `*`.

```
#define reduce(F,X) (reduce)(*#F,X)
int (reduce)(char f, arr a); /* perform binary operation F upon adjacent elements of vector X, right to left,
                                   reducing vector to a single value */
```

So the `binop` does a loop and a switch on the operator character.

```
/* perform binary operation F upon corresponding elements of vectors X and Y */
#define BINOP(f,F,id) case f: *elem(z,i) = *elem(x,i) F *elem(y,i); break;
arr (binop)(arr x, char f, arr y){
    arr z=copy(x);
    int n=x->dims[0];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        switch(f){
            OPERATORS(BINOP)
        }
    }
    return z;
}
#undef BINOP
```

And the reduce function does a backwards loop if there are enough elements, having set the initial value to the last element if there was one, having preset the initial value to the operator's identity element.

```
/* perform binary operation F upon adjacent elements of vector X, right to left,
   reducing vector to a single value */
#define REDID(f,F,id) case f: x = id; break;
#define REDOP(f,F,id) case f: x = *elem(a,i) F x; break;
int (reduce)(char f, arr a){
    int n = a->dims[0];
    int x;
    int i;
    switch(f){
        OPERATORS(REDID)
    }
    if (n) {
        x=*elem(a,n-1);
        for (i=n-2;i>=0;i--){
            switch(f){
                OPERATORS(REDOP)
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}
#undef REDID
#undef REDOP
```

And with these tools, inner product can be implemented in a higher-level manner.

```
/* perform a (2D) matrix multiplication upon rows of x and columns of y
   using operations F and G.
       Z = X F.G Y
       Z[i,j] = F/ X[i,*] G Y'[j,*]

   more generally,
   perform an inner product on arguments of compatible dimension.
       Z = X[A;B;C;D;E;F] +.* Y[G;H;I;J;K]  |(F = G)
       Z[A;B;C;D;E;H;I;J;K] = +/ X[A;B;C;D;E;*] * Y[*;H;I;J;K]
 */
arr (matmul)(arr x, char f, char g, arr y){
    int i,j;
    arr xdims = cast(x->dims,1,x->rank);
    arr ydims = cast(y->dims,1,y->rank);
    xdims->dims[0]--;
    ydims->dims[0]--;
    ydims->data++;
    arr z=arraya(x->rank+y->rank-2,catv(xdims,ydims)->data);
    int datasz = productdims(z->rank,z->dims);
    int k=y->dims[0];
    arr xs = NULL;
    arr ys = NULL;

    for (i=0; i<datasz; i++){
        int idx[x->rank+y->rank];
        vector_index(i,z->dims,z->rank,idx);
        int *xdex=idx;
        int *ydex=idx+x->rank-1;
        memmove(ydex+1,ydex,y->rank);
        xdex[x->rank-1] = -1;
        free(xs);
        free(ys);
        xs = slicea(x,xdex);
        ys = slicea(y,ydex);
        z->data[i] = (reduce)(f,(binop)(xs,g,ys));
    }

    free(xs);
    free(ys);
    free(xdims);
    free(ydims);
    return z;
}
```

This function also uses the functions `cast` which presents a varargs interface to `casta`.

```
/* create an array header to access existing data in multidimensional layout */
arr cast(int *data, int rank, ...){
    va_list ap;
    int dims[rank];

    va_start(ap,rank);
    loaddimsv(rank,dims,ap);
    va_end(ap);

    return casta(data, rank, dims);
}
```

And it also uses `vector_index` to convert a 1D index into an nD vector of indices.

```
/* compute vector index list for ravel index ind */
int *vector_index(int ind, int *dims, int n, int *vec){
    int i,t=ind, *z=vec;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        z[n-1-i] = t % dims[n-1-i];
        t /= dims[n-1-i];
    }
    return z;
}
```

[github file](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/master/arrind.c#L404). Additional supporting functions are also in the github file.

---

This Q/A pair is part of a series of related issues which arose in implementing [inca](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/) an interpreter for the APL language written in C. Others: [How can I work with dynamically-allocated arbitrary-dimensional arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023867/how-can-i-work-with-dynamically-allocated-arbitrary-dimensional-arrays) , and [How to pass a C math operator (+-*/%) into a function result=mathfunc(x,+,y);?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960273/how-to-pass-a-c-math-operator-into-a-function-result-mathfuncx-y) . Some of this material was previously posted to [comp.lang.c](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.c/Z0mycsYvPyI/discussion). More background in [comp.lang.apl](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.apl/zCPJ8KaZyWg/0U_pC9skLbUJ).

Comment: [Print function](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c/Z0mycsYvPyI/WvtkJZGebfIJ).

Comment: This is the best answer i have ever seen. Thank you <3