# Declaring pointer to a 3 by 3 array and using pointer to print it

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

How can i declare a pointer to an array of 3 by 3 and use that pointer to print it....  The compiler is giving the error "[Error] subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector "

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int A[3][3][3]={0};

    int *ptr=A;
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<3;k++)
            {
                printf("%d    ",*ptr[i][j][k] );
            }
            puts("");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not an array of `3` by `3` it's a 3x3x3 array which is usually not useful for anything.

Comment: `int (*ptr)[3][3]=A;` ... `printf("%d ", ptr[i][j][k] );`

Comment: Don't use multidimensional arrays in C. Use only 1D arrays, then `arr[i*width+j]` etc...

Comment: [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409991/use-a-dope-vector-to-access-arbitrary-axial-slices-of-a-multidimensional-array/30409992#30409992) shows how to encapsulate a multidimensional array into a struct which can be passed around. I also have a [print function here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c/Z0mycsYvPyI/WvtkJZGebfIJ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are declaring a pointer to an `int`, and casting an array to it. This is incorrect, because a pointer has one implicit "dimension" (and hence allows a single dereference), while your array has three dimensions.

To fix the problem, declare `ptr` as a pointer to a 3×3 array:

```
int (*ptr)[3][3]=A;
```

in which case you need to remove the dereference operator when accessing array elements

```
printf("%d    ", ptr[i][j][k]);
```

[demo 1.](http://ideone.com/8S1h7L)

or a pointer to a 3×3×3 array

```
int (*ptr)[3][3][3]=&A;
```

in which case you need to dereference the pointer before applying indexes to it:

```
printf("%d    ", (*ptr)[i][j][k]);
```

[demo 2.](http://ideone.com/S9YRXw)

Answer (score 2):

Any multidimensional array is in fact a one dimensional array elements of which are in turn arrays.

This declaration

```
int A[3][3][3]={0};
```

can be rewritten the following way

```
typedef int T[3][3];

T A[3];
```

So you have an array `A` elements of which have type `int[3][3]`
If you want to declare a pointer to the first element of the array then you have to write

```
T *ptr = A;
```

where `ptr` is a pointer to objects of type `T`. As `T` is an alias for `int[3][3]` then the preceding declaration can be rewritten like

```
int ( *ptr )[3][3] = A;
```

In this case the loops will look like

```
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
      for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      {
           for(k=0;k<3;k++)
           {
               printf("%d    ", ptr[i][j][k] );
           }

      puts("");

      }
  }
```

If you want to declare a pointer to the whole array itself then you can write

```
int ( *ptr )[3][3][3] = &A;
```

and the loops will look like

```
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
      for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      {
           for(k=0;k<3;k++)
           {
               printf("%d    ", ( *ptr )[i][j][k] );
           }

      puts("");

      }
  }
```

But I am sure that in your assignment you need to use a pointer to the first element of the array as I showed initially.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that accessing a pointer value with index notation works for a single index if the pointer is a single star pointer, like this

```
printf("%d\t", ptr[i + 3 * j + 9 * k]);
```

A three star pointer `int ***ptr` would allow the syntax `ptr[i][j][k]` but it would be wrong, because the pointer would point to a pointer of `int` pointers, which means that the data is arranged in a different way than that of the array `int A[3][3][3]`, the array is more like a `int *ptr` pointer, because the integers are stored contigously.

In the `int ***` approach, it would be like an array of pointers to arrays of `int` pointers. Which means that `ptr[i]` would be equivalent to `*(ptr + i)` which is the same as `*((char ***)ptr + sizeof(int **))`, since `sizeof(int **)` is not necessarily the same as<sup>1</sup> `sizeof(int)`, then it would increment the pointer a different ammount than needed, leading to an obvious problem, the dereferenced pointer would not be pointing to the right place.

You could always declare pointers to arrays as the other answers mention, but I will skip that part, since it's in the other answers.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>It could be by coincidence the same.</sub>